# Gurobi if condition with "or"

Tags: python, gurobi

I have to implement the restriction seen in the photo for a vehicle routing problem in Python Gurobi. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it with the "or"...

[image: restriction]

the x variable is defined like:

> xw =myModel.addVars(A, lb=0.0, vtype=gpy.GRB.BINARY, name="Walking")

Also quantity V`is known and Qv and Qw are known

My approach is the following, but it was missing the vi > Qv or wi > Qw condition (see photo).

> myModel.addConstrs((xw[(i,j)]
> == xw[(i,j)] for i in V_Kunde), name="9Constraint")

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: What is `wi`? A decision variable or a given constant?

Comment: wi and vi are parts out of a quantity, which is fixed. So for example Qw = 20. Then w1 = 10, w2 = 10 and w3 = 20. vi = 40 which ist higher than 20. So the binary variable xw should be 0.

Comment: It's still not clear what `A`, `V_Kunde` and `V'` are, i.e. how the decision variable `xw` is indexed. I'd recommend providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).